# Problema con menu desplegable en movil css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un problema con mi menu desplegable, al dar click en el icono para abrir el menu todo bien, pero cuando deslizo mas abajo en la pagina y lo intento abrir otra vez, al abrirlo me devuelve al tope de la pagina y no se por que, les dejo unas imagenes y mi codigo

**CODIGOHTML**

```
<header>
    <a href="#" id="menu" class="menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="menu-container">
    <div class="container-items">
        <a href="#" class="item">item</a>
        <a href="" class="item">item</a>
        <a href="" class="item">item</a>
        <a href="" class="item">item</a>
        <a href="" class="item">item</a>
        <a href="" class="item">item</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CODIGO CSS**

```
.menu-container {
position: fixed;
width: 70%;
height: 100vh;
left: -80%;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s;
background: #1d1d1d;
z-index: 2000; }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que el que deberia tener position fixed es el header y el container position absolute y darle la ubicacion deseada

Answer (score 2):

`<a href="#"`  hace referencia al top de la página, para q no salte hay que evitar o cancelar el comportamiento usando javascript, `onclick="return false;"` debería bastar salvo que haya un listener por ahi que haga otras cosas como cambiar una clase o el icono de cerrar.

```css
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<header>
  <a href="#" onclick="return false;" id="menu" class="menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
</header>
<div class="menu-container">
  <div class="container-items">
    <a href="#uno" class="item">item</a>
    <a href="#dos" class="item">item</a>
    <a href="#tres" class="item">item</a>
    <a href="#cuatro" class="item">item</a>
    <a href="#cinco" class="item">item</a>
    <a href="#seis" class="item">item</a>
  </div>
</div>
<main>
  <div id="lipsum">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec mattis eget ante quis eleifend. Maecenas vitae lacus quis nibh laoreet vulputate sed quis nisl. Quisque ac odio sollicitudin, condimentum sapien vitae, dignissim est. Etiam quis tellus et
      lacus consequat aliquam. Phasellus et tellus mauris. Nulla turpis risus, tristique quis lectus a, blandit porttitor lacus. Donec eget nulla ac quam tempor porttitor et et augue. Nullam quis tellus ex. Sed molestie, velit vel posuere malesuada, lectus
      odio aliquam lorem, sit amet ultricies odio ligula et lectus. Quisque tempus nunc in dictum viverra. Ut vitae suscipit quam. Nulla pellentesque pellentesque metus, vitae rutrum erat lobortis vel.
    </p>
    <p>
      Quisque ullamcorper nunc sit amet ligula ullamcorper, ac pellentesque nisl dignissim. Duis sagittis diam neque, non tempus sem molestie non. Quisque lacinia varius urna, eu tristique massa fermentum eu. Donec eget egestas nisi, quis eleifend nisl. Vivamus
      tincidunt elit ut ligula mattis, ac fermentum est sollicitudin. Curabitur feugiat nunc et faucibus congue. Nam ullamcorper nunc sed mauris gravida, blandit finibus purus pretium. Sed ullamcorper massa eros, at vehicula nisi ultricies vel. Proin
      tincidunt aliquet ex, ut feugiat magna. Donec id blandit velit. Aliquam in pretium quam. Nulla sed mauris a eros efficitur varius eu at sapien. In consequat, quam sit amet semper imperdiet, felis libero scelerisque eros, pellentesque elementum turpis
      enim et neque. Phasellus porta in justo mollis semper. Donec nisi magna, dapibus sit amet nibh non, iaculis faucibus ipsum. Sed fermentum augue in facilisis ultrices.
    </p>
    <p>
      Sed rhoncus porttitor orci in accumsan. Sed placerat turpis eu tellus elementum, ullamcorper condimentum eros tincidunt. Cras a scelerisque mi. Donec sem nunc, sollicitudin eget sagittis at, lacinia sed quam. Duis massa enim, sagittis a imperdiet ut,
      maximus vitae odio. Morbi et mi in libero tincidunt commodo congue sed lectus. Nunc convallis id risus ac eleifend.
    </p>
    <p><a id=uno />
      <a href=# onclick="return false;">clickme</a> Curabitur in est a velit luctus vestibulum sit amet quis neque. Vivamus nec turpis orci. Morbi et bibendum sapien, sed finibus massa. Quisque quis fringilla quam. Praesent eu bibendum sapien, quis finibus
      dui. Proin vitae dui justo. Suspendisse auctor congue diam a laoreet. Pellentesque ornare quam nec pretium posuere. Quisque efficitur faucibus felis, eu venenatis mauris luctus vitae. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra,
      per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce dolor nulla, tempus et condimentum eget, commodo nec nisi. Donec sodales ex ut est interdum tempor. Nulla facilisi.
    </p>
    <p>
      Donec ac mollis justo, id eleifend odio. Integer aliquam odio sed imperdiet volutpat. Cras in eros elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Suspendisse bibendum nibh nisl, laoreet scelerisque arcu luctus
      id. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed luctus cursus augue eu viverra. Donec et egestas risus.
    </p>
  </div>
</main>
```

---

En caso de que haya un evento escuchando el click/tap le agregas el preventdefault y el return false a la función correspondiente.

```js
var elBoton = document.getElementById('menu');

elBoton.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var elMenu = document.querySelector('.menu-container')
  elMenu.classList.add('abierto')
  return false;
})
```

```css
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.menu-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100vh;
  left: -80%;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  background: #1d1d1d;
  z-index: 2000;
}

.menu-container.abierto {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<header>
  <a href="#" id="menu" class="menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
</header>
<div class="menu-container">
  <div class="container-items">
    <a href="#uno" class="item">item</a>
    <a href="#dos" class="item">item</a>
    <a href="#tres" class="item">item</a>
    <a href="#cuatro" class="item">item</a>
    <a href="#cinco" class="item">item</a>
    <a href="#seis" class="item">item</a>
  </div>
</div>
<main>
  <div id="lipsum">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec mattis eget ante quis eleifend. Maecenas vitae lacus quis nibh laoreet vulputate sed quis nisl. Quisque ac odio sollicitudin, condimentum sapien vitae, dignissim est. Etiam quis tellus et
      lacus consequat aliquam. Phasellus et tellus mauris. Nulla turpis risus, tristique quis lectus a, blandit porttitor lacus. Donec eget nulla ac quam tempor porttitor et et augue. Nullam quis tellus ex. Sed molestie, velit vel posuere malesuada, lectus
      odio aliquam lorem, sit amet ultricies odio ligula et lectus. Quisque tempus nunc in dictum viverra. Ut vitae suscipit quam. Nulla pellentesque pellentesque metus, vitae rutrum erat lobortis vel.
    </p>
    <p>
      Quisque ullamcorper nunc sit amet ligula ullamcorper, ac pellentesque nisl dignissim. Duis sagittis diam neque, non tempus sem molestie non. Quisque lacinia varius urna, eu tristique massa fermentum eu. Donec eget egestas nisi, quis eleifend nisl. Vivamus
      tincidunt elit ut ligula mattis, ac fermentum est sollicitudin. Curabitur feugiat nunc et faucibus congue. Nam ullamcorper nunc sed mauris gravida, blandit finibus purus pretium. Sed ullamcorper massa eros, at vehicula nisi ultricies vel. Proin
      tincidunt aliquet ex, ut feugiat magna. Donec id blandit velit. Aliquam in pretium quam. Nulla sed mauris a eros efficitur varius eu at sapien. In consequat, quam sit amet semper imperdiet, felis libero scelerisque eros, pellentesque elementum turpis
      enim et neque. Phasellus porta in justo mollis semper. Donec nisi magna, dapibus sit amet nibh non, iaculis faucibus ipsum. Sed fermentum augue in facilisis ultrices.
    </p>
    <p>
      Sed rhoncus porttitor orci in accumsan. Sed placerat turpis eu tellus elementum, ullamcorper condimentum eros tincidunt. Cras a scelerisque mi. Donec sem nunc, sollicitudin eget sagittis at, lacinia sed quam. Duis massa enim, sagittis a imperdiet ut,
      maximus vitae odio. Morbi et mi in libero tincidunt commodo congue sed lectus. Nunc convallis id risus ac eleifend.
    </p>
    <p><a id=uno />
      <a href=# onclick="return false;">clickme</a> Curabitur in est a velit luctus vestibulum sit amet quis neque. Vivamus nec turpis orci. Morbi et bibendum sapien, sed finibus massa. Quisque quis fringilla quam. Praesent eu bibendum sapien, quis finibus
      dui. Proin vitae dui justo. Suspendisse auctor congue diam a laoreet. Pellentesque ornare quam nec pretium posuere. Quisque efficitur faucibus felis, eu venenatis mauris luctus vitae. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra,
      per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce dolor nulla, tempus et condimentum eget, commodo nec nisi. Donec sodales ex ut est interdum tempor. Nulla facilisi.
    </p>
    <p>
      Donec ac mollis justo, id eleifend odio. Integer aliquam odio sed imperdiet volutpat. Cras in eros elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Suspendisse bibendum nibh nisl, laoreet scelerisque arcu luctus
      id. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed luctus cursus augue eu viverra. Donec et egestas risus.
    </p>
  </div>
</main>
```

---

va de yapa un menu con checkbox sin javascript

```css
input#abreMenu {
  display: none;
}

input#abreMenu+label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 3000;
  color: #fe0;
  background: black;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

input#abreMenu+label .cierra {
  display: none;
}

input#abreMenu:checked+label .abre {
  display: none;
}

input#abreMenu:checked+label .cierra {
  display: block;
}

input#abreMenu:checked~.menu-container {
  left: 0
}

main {
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.menu-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100vh;
  left: -80%;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  background: #1d1d1d;
  z-index: 2000;
}

.container-items>a {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<header>
  <input type=checkbox id=abreMenu />
  <label for=abreMenu>
<span class=abre>
  <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </span>
<span class=cierra>
  <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
</span>
</label>
  <div class="menu-container">
    <div class="container-items">
      <a href="#uno" class="item">item</a>
      <a href="#dos" class="item">item</a>
      <a href="#tres" class="item">item</a>
      <a href="#cuatro" class="item">item</a>
      <a href="#cinco" class="item">item</a>
      <a href="#seis" class="item">item</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <div id="lipsum">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec mattis eget ante quis eleifend. Maecenas vitae lacus quis nibh laoreet vulputate sed quis nisl. Quisque ac odio sollicitudin, condimentum sapien vitae, dignissim est. Etiam quis tellus et
      lacus consequat aliquam. Phasellus et tellus mauris. Nulla turpis risus, tristique quis lectus a, blandit porttitor lacus. Donec eget nulla ac quam tempor porttitor et et augue. Nullam quis tellus ex. Sed molestie, velit vel posuere malesuada, lectus
      odio aliquam lorem, sit amet ultricies odio ligula et lectus. Quisque tempus nunc in dictum viverra. Ut vitae suscipit quam. Nulla pellentesque pellentesque metus, vitae rutrum erat lobortis vel.
    </p>
    <p>
      Quisque ullamcorper nunc sit amet ligula ullamcorper, ac pellentesque nisl dignissim. Duis sagittis diam neque, non tempus sem molestie non. Quisque lacinia varius urna, eu tristique massa fermentum eu. Donec eget egestas nisi, quis eleifend nisl. Vivamus
      tincidunt elit ut ligula mattis, ac fermentum est sollicitudin. Curabitur feugiat nunc et faucibus congue. Nam ullamcorper nunc sed mauris gravida, blandit finibus purus pretium. Sed ullamcorper massa eros, at vehicula nisi ultricies vel. Proin
      tincidunt aliquet ex, ut feugiat magna. Donec id blandit velit. Aliquam in pretium quam. Nulla sed mauris a eros efficitur varius eu at sapien. In consequat, quam sit amet semper imperdiet, felis libero scelerisque eros, pellentesque elementum turpis
      enim et neque. Phasellus porta in justo mollis semper. Donec nisi magna, dapibus sit amet nibh non, iaculis faucibus ipsum. Sed fermentum augue in facilisis ultrices.
    </p>
    <p>
      Sed rhoncus porttitor orci in accumsan. Sed placerat turpis eu tellus elementum, ullamcorper condimentum eros tincidunt. Cras a scelerisque mi. Donec sem nunc, sollicitudin eget sagittis at, lacinia sed quam. Duis massa enim, sagittis a imperdiet ut,
      maximus vitae odio. Morbi et mi in libero tincidunt commodo congue sed lectus. Nunc convallis id risus ac eleifend.
    </p>
    <p><a id=uno />
      <a href=# onclick="return false;">clickme</a> Curabitur in est a velit luctus vestibulum sit amet quis neque. Vivamus nec turpis orci. Morbi et bibendum sapien, sed finibus massa. Quisque quis fringilla quam. Praesent eu bibendum sapien, quis finibus
      dui. Proin vitae dui justo. Suspendisse auctor congue diam a laoreet. Pellentesque ornare quam nec pretium posuere. Quisque efficitur faucibus felis, eu venenatis mauris luctus vitae. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra,
      per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce dolor nulla, tempus et condimentum eget, commodo nec nisi. Donec sodales ex ut est interdum tempor. Nulla facilisi.
    </p>
    <p>
      Donec ac mollis justo, id eleifend odio. Integer aliquam odio sed imperdiet volutpat. Cras in eros elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Suspendisse bibendum nibh nisl, laoreet scelerisque arcu luctus
      id. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed luctus cursus augue eu viverra. Donec et egestas risus.
    </p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

He estado probándolo y la verdad es que no puedo reproducir tu problema porque me falta parte del CSS y JavaScript, aun así he intentado reconstruirlo a mi manera.

Principalmente la barra de navegación debe ir en el header, junto con su botón para abrir o cerrar, así cuando hagas scroll el botón no se sale del viewport.

Ahora el código:

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <a href="#" id="menu" class="menu" onclick=(toggleNavBar())><i class="fas fa-bars"></i>Toggle</a>
    <div id="navbar" class="menu-container">
        <a href="#" class="item">item</a>
        <a href="" class="item">item</a>
        <a href="" class="item">item</a>
        <a href="" class="item">item</a>
        <a href="" class="item">item</a>
        <a href="" class="item">item</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  height: 200vh;
}

#menu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
}

#navbar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100vh;
    left: -80%;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    background: #1d1d1d;
    z-index: 98;
    padding-top: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**JS**

```javascript
function toggleNavBar() {
    let navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
  if (navbar.style.left == '-80%') {
    navbar.style.left = '0%';
  } else if (navbar.style.left == '') {
    navbar.style.left = '0%';
  } else {
    navbar.style.left = '-80%'
  }
}
```

Pruébalo en [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) antes de implementarlo.
No sé si era lo que estabas buscando, pero aquí tienes un código funcional.

Supongo que estás empezando, te deseo mucha suerte y ánimo.

Por cierto, tal vez te venga bien saber que las transiciones son más óptimas usando `transform` en vez de cambiar la propiedad `left` de forma directa, te recomiendo leer esto:

https://medium.com/outsystems-experts/how-to-achieve-60-fps-animations-with-css3-db7b98610108